# Add translucent box under sticky header

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, sticky

I'm looking to update the CSS of this site http://www.zackseckler.com/ so that the sticky header has a translucent or opaque box underneath the text & logo (to make it more visible). Any thoughts on how to proceed?

I've tried the below but to no avail...

```
#header {
margin-left: 0px;
width: auto;
height: 90px;
padding: 0px;
padding-left:185px;
font-size: 35px; color:#FFFFFF; 
background-color: #f6c491;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;}
```

Thanks,
zack

Comment: add a background :rgba()/hsla() color or even a linear-gradient  to tune opacity, and turn the margin-top into padding-top ....

Answer (score 0):

In case you've read my initial answer, forget it, I missread the whole thing.

First, I'm not sure where you got the #header id, because I don't see it anywhere on your website.
Second, you were on the right path. You just have to set a transparent background and use paddings instead of margin (in your case). You can play with the opacity if you want, now it's set to 0.98

Just replace this part in your stylesheet at line 437 (or somewhere near)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .header.stacked {
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        background: rgba(246,246,246,0.98);
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis! Is there a way to make that change in the CSS User Stylesheet? The coding isn't accessible by lines (and I'm a beginner with CSS)

Comment: You could search (Ctrl +F) for **.header.stacked** and you should find the same thing that I wrote above, but with slightly different attributes and values, then you would replace the entire thing (from **@media** to last **}**).
In case you don't find it, just add it add the bottom of the stylesheet, should work.

Comment: Dennis, this is the only code I could find (couldn't paste whole thing)...no mention of @media

<header class="header {{ theme.menu_layout_type | downcase }} {% if theme.menu_fixed_position %}fixed{% endif %}">
    <div class="wrapper">
        {% theme_include 'partials/menu_toggle_button' %}
        {% theme_include 'partials/logo' %}
        {% if theme.show_social_icons_in_navigation %}
            {% if theme.menu_layout_type == 'Stacked' %}
                {% theme_include 'partials/social' %}
                {% theme_include 'partials/menu' %}

Comment: You're looking at the wrong file :)  
You should look for something with the **.css** extension, for example it could be named stylesheet.css, style.css or anything else.css.  
Then do what I've written in my previous comment.